# If we had a art/craft exchange, who would participate?

Tags: discussion

I don't have details but I wanted to see how interested people are in this.

We got several upvotes on the "Secret Santa" idea on the one-year celebration idea generation question, so I thought I'd get a handle on who would actually be interested to see how formalized we need to make it (or if enough people would want to do it to make it worth it).

[Code Review](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/code-reviews-secret-santa-2015) has apparently done these in the past and they use a specialized [web tool](https://www.drawnames.com/how-to-draw-names) to randomly assign people to their trade members. From there, the tool allows people to anonymously message each other to get information - in our case, mailing address and perhaps favorite colors or other things.

---

In general, I'd say we'd need to set some ground rules:

- must be handmade by you
- materials value limit
- finished size (while you may be willing to ship it, the receiver will likely be better able to keep it if it's small)

Any other rules?

---

I'd have to say that I have a couple of concerns - mostly in relation to the release of PII (personally identifying information - SE has strict policies about release of this information, so we want to be cautious). If we use the web tool, you will have control over this through so only the person sending you a gift will know the information but you will not know who that person is (assuming they don't tell you). If you are concerned about giving out your home address, consider seeing if there's a third party that could accept the package for you - a delivery center, for example.

Note, we are an international site so, depending on who decided to participate, you may need to mail something internationally. Fortunately, most countries don't charge tariffs on items classified as "gifts", so you shouldn't have to pay more than postage but international shipping is often more likely to be held up in processing or lost outright. Make sure to retain any tracking documentation you're given.

Please post an answer below if you have any other concerns.

---

If you are interested in signing up, add your username to this list (if you can't edit on Meta, comment and if you can't comment, flag.):

- Matt
- whrrgarbl
- Catija
- magerber
- Willeke

Comment: I suppose username should be unique for us for now. I could not find any obvious duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

We should encourage users to declare allergies and sensitivities. Smoke, dander and scented items are possibilities to consider. Anyone participating should make sure others are aware in some way I think.

I don't know if it will be an issue but since people could theoretically craft anything we need to be careful about border laws with certain things. Like if someone wanted to ship palm fronds for example there might be laws preventing the transport of plant material. Or bone or something.....